# What is the overall idea of Galois theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, field-theory, galois-theory, big-picture

I am a third year undergraduate, doing a course on Field and Galois theory. Now, while I seem to understand most of the concepts locally, **I do not seem to get the 'Whole picture' of what is happening in Galois theory**, and things seem to be a bit disconnected. I would be grateful if some could help me get an overall picture of the subject. The whole, I believe, is greater than the sum of its parts.

I am familiar with the concepts of field theory, such as extensions, separability, splitting fields, finite fields and all the other basic concepts you would expect to know to study Galois theory, and also have a fair understanding of the main concepts of Galois theory. I just dont get the whole picture. Thanks.

Comment: Start with the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) (for finite Galois extensions, and infinite ones). This gives a good idea about the whole picture.

Comment: Just to check... have you reached the fundamental theorem of Galois theory yet? In order to reach the key results in Galois theory you have to start by introducing Field theory... but this is just the introduction

Comment: A rational polynomial is solvable by radicals if, and only if, its Galois group is solvable.

Comment: As others have pointed out, one of the central points of Galois theory is that you can study field extensions by doing group theory.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes, Fundamental theorem of Galois theory has been covered.

Comment: The idea is even more general. Having some object, you can get to study the objects containing your object or that are contained in your object by looking at the subgroups of the group of automorphisms of your object. Mainly, you can get results in your subject via group theory.

Comment: @Lolman Let me clarify if I understand correctly what you mean by 'objects'. If I understand correctly, a specific case of 'objects', which are usually taught, are the Fields, polynomials over fields, and their roots, where we get information about the roots of polynomials over some field $F$, by considering a particular subgroup of the group of automorphisms of a particular field extension of $F$. Do I understand correctly? And in case I have understood correctly, could you give some more examples of what else these 'objects' could be?

Comment: @user138359 in the chapter 1.3 about covering spaces in Hatcher, Algebraic topology we relate a locally simply connected topological space with its fundamental group, and the subgroups of it as all the possible connected coverings of it.

On a different note: Jacobson's Basic Algebra 2 page 467 we have a relation between subfields with finite codimensions of some field $E$ correspond to a set of endomorphisms of $E$.

Comment: @user138359 the point is understanding what it means for an extension to be normal in your context. When it corresponds to a normal subgroup.

Comment: @user138359 I looked better into it and it may be the only example, so it may be indeed a way, but apart from the case of fields and the case of topological spaces.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have read it, but the problem is that I find the large number of concepts that are introduced in a very short time to be a bit overwhelming. I am not able to see a natural link between the different parts of the proof of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, and Galois theory in general.

Comment: @Lolman (and maybe not so interesting for the OP) If you would like to see your idea more formalised, including more examples, you could have a look at http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf

Comment: @Louis Good guy Lenstra! But I'd say that this is a subcase of what i was saying, because here you consider schemes rather than topological spaces. The interesting fact is that we consider curves and field extensions as different things, but if we consider for example the equivalence between trascendental extension of degree one of $\mathbb{C}$ and compact Riemann surfaces we see a connection between the two!

Comment: @Lolman If you read the script more carefully, you will see that there they do not treat a subcase but indeed the case of galois categories which is the abstract notion that describes how (e.g.) étale coverings, topological coverings and galois extensions are 'connected'. Indeed, one of the main results is that each Galois Category is equivalent to a category of G-sets for some group G. (Theorem 3.5). For the case of topological coverings see Theorem 1.15. For Galois extensions it should be Theorem 2.9.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for pointing it out! I will look into it tomorrow!

Comment: I would like to add something here; Galois theory in the case of field extensions gave a new approach to studying many objects throughout mathematics. The idea behind the approach is to study invariant sub-objects! --- In the case of field extensions we classify the intermediate fields as fields which are invariant under the action of subgroups of the Galois group. 

This idea of invariance under a group action started with Galois theory and is now ubiquitous in algebra, algebraic geometry topology... All over the place!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Galois theory is a branch of abstract algebra that gives a connection between field theory and group theory, by reducing field theoretic problems to group theoretic problems.

It started out by using permutation groups to give a description of how various roots of a polynomial equation are related, but nowadays, Galois theory has expanded to involve automorphisms of field extensions.

It was motivated by looking for the roots of fifth degree polynomials in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial using algebraic operations and the application of radicals. Galois answered this question and gave us a method for examining/checking that an equation higher degree can be solved in this way.

The epitome of Galois theory is the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. It describes the structure of field extensions. It says that for a finite and Galois field extension $E/F,$ there is a one-to-one correspondence between its intermediate fields and subgroups of its Galois group.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks.